# help with jquery slider range option

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Is there a way to limit the slider options in jQuery UI slider?

I have a slider that is broken up into 5 parts.

However, I only want options 2,3, and 4 available.  I don't want the handle to go to 1 or 5.

how do you restrict this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can listen to the ***slide event*** and test for it's position.

When it's at **1** or **5**, you can `return false` and cancel the event.

**This seems to work**

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    value: 2,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
       if(ui.value == 1 || ui.value == 5)
           return false;
    }
});
```

Have a play [here](http://jsfiddle.net/marko/3QVUf/1/).

Comment: Marko..that was awesome!  I learned something today :)  Thank you very much.  I love Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change setting to do this if you want to keep 1 and 5 on the slider. If you only want 2,3 & 4 you can use:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({ min: 2, max: 4 });
```

If you want to keep 1 and 5 you will need to write an onChange function. Similar to:

```
$( ".selector" ).slider({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
       this.value == 1? this.value = 2: this.value; //
       this.value == 5? this.value = 4: this.value;
   }
});
```

Not sure if that is the right syntax, you will need to check.